# Obtener resultado mediante condicion guardada en tabla

Tags: php, condiciones

No sé si sería posible poder hacer un `select` y realizar una  condición y ejecutarla  para ver si cumple.

La idea de negocio sería vender tablas a cierta medida y si el cliente desea agregar o quitarle medidas a la tabla, se le debe asignar un valor extra.

Ejemplo: Si el cliente compra tabla `AA1` y desea agregarle `200` ml más, este tendria un valor adicional de `2000` al precio real.

```
------------------------------------
| Producto | Condicion | Adicional |
-----------|-----------|-----------|
| AA1      |  x =< 100 |  1000     |  
| AA1      |  x >  200 |  2000     |  
| AA2      |  x >  300 |  2000     |  
| AA3      |  x => 100 |  4000     |  
|----------|-----------|-----------|

    $medida = 200;
    $producto = 'AA1';
   /* En esta condicion deberia obtener un adicional 2000 */
    $sql = SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Producto = '$producto'";
```

Espero haberme explicado bien.

Comment: Lo que quieres es conseguir que te devuelva todos los adicionales que tengan como valor el 2000 cuando hagas el select?

Comment: Otra cosa que quiero comentar es que no entiendo el sentido de tener guardada una condicion en una tabla pero si lo que quieres es obtener el 2000 respecto a esas condiciones entonces en lugar de concentrarse en el numero 2000 deberias de mejor concentrarte en obtener la condicion como tal. Pero lo que se me hace raro es que por ejemplo dos condiciones diferentes sean las que te devuelven el valor 2000 asi que eso romperia todo lo que te acabo de decir.

Comment: No se entiende la pregunta. ¿Qué es lo que quieres filtrar? Pon un ejemplo de los resultados esperados. ¿Dónde se determina la medida? ¿No tienes guardada la medida? ¿Por qué no la tienes guardada?

Comment: esto suena demasiado complejo. la pregunta seria por que?

Comment: @ASASCED Quiero que me devuelva el adicional si cumple con el SELECT del Producto y que cumpla la condicion que se obtiene. Ejemplo el AA1 tiene 2 lineas pero una de ella cumple la condicion

Comment: @A.Cedano Quiero hacer un select a un producto y si este cumple la condicion obtener el valor adicional. Tengo una variable `$medida` para comprar la condicion

Comment: Sigo sin entender por qué la condición no es guardada como tal en ninguna parte. En una tienda o almacén supongo que los productos se guardan por medidas, tamaños, colores, etc en una tabla de inventario u otra. Mi pregunta iba en ese sentido: ¿por qué esa condición no está guardada como tal en tu modelo? ¿cómo sacarías un reporte sobre cuántos productos `AA1` de tamaño  `200` hay  actualmente o cuántos productos `BB1` de color rojo hay y cuántos de color `blanco` con medida `300`? Es que creo que tu error está a nivel de diseño lo cual es muy grave.

Comment: Lo que pasa que producto `AA1` tiene ya una medida, pero si el usuario desea agregar o quitarle medida, a este se le agrega un valor adicional acuerdo a las condiciones.

Comment: Sigo sin entender. ¿Cómo es eso de que el usuario le puede quitar  una medida? Pulsa en [edit] y explica mejor el contexto porque no entiendo nada. ¿Hablamos de un contexto en el que el usuario crea productos con medidas que él mismo elige y luego guarda ese producto? Si es así habría que inventariar ese producto guardando sus propiedades aparte.

Comment: Creo que ya entendi la pregunta. Esperame 5 minutos y te respondo.

Comment: Finalmente cree una funcion donde `explode` la condicion y despues agrego un switch preguntado por las 5 futura condiciones` "<=","<",">=",">","=="`

Answer (score 0):

Bien, de acuerdo a los comentarios y a lo que yo mismo veo es que quieres que te devuelva el valor adicional con respecto a la condicion ingresada en la tabla de condiciones, y tomas el valor de tabla de condiciones con respecto al producto, entonces si la nueva medida ingresada por ejemplo en el producto AA2 le das una medida agregada de 200 no deveria de devolver el valor agregado pero si agregas un 301 o mas deberia de devolver el valor adicional de 2000. Si es que asi es la condicion entonces deberias de hacer lo siguiente.

```
------------------------------------
| Producto | Condicion | Adicional |
-----------|-----------|-----------|
| AA1      |  x =< 100 |  1000     |  
| AA1      |  x >  200 |  2000     |  
| AA2      |  x >  300 |  2000     |  
| AA3      |  x => 100 |  4000     |  
|----------|-----------|-----------|

$medida = 400;
$producto = 'AA2';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Producto = '$producto'";

$condicion = "SELECT Condicion FROM TABLE WHERE Producto = '$producto'";

if($condicion == 'x = 100') {
    if($medida > 300 ) {
       $valorAdicional = "SELECT Adicional FROM TABLE WHERE Producto = '$producto'";
    }
} else {
    echo 'No hay valor adicional';
}
```

No puedes tomar directamente la condicion y pasarla por un if ni nada pero podrias sacar individualmente y compararlos con otro string similar y que te haga la operacion, despues de todo las operaciones solo serian `>, <, >=, <=, ==` Pero no se si utilizarias todas, esta es la solucion que se me ocurre y no se si cumpla con lo que comentaste pero revisala.

Comment: Esto es un sinsentido.. si se agrega cualquier tipo de condicion entonces hay que modificar el programa, y entonces no tiene sentido tener las reglas de negocios en una fila de la tabla.. o sea, la respuesta es correcta, la idea, no tiene ningun sentido.

Comment: @gbianchi lo mismo pienso, pues se trata de una serie de condiciones que estan dentro de una tabla cosa la cual no deberia de pasar, no debe de haber condiciones en una tabla, toda la logica de un programa deberia de estar en el codigo y las tablas solo deben de tener datos e indentificadores. Para mi una mejor solucion a esto es que agregara esas condiciones como id de acuerdo a algun tipo de operacion en especifico y que lo reconociera en el codigo de forma mas natural pero bueno, aun asi no entiendo el contexto de todo el programa ni nada de eso.

Comment: Tampoco se trata de *agregar condiciones con un ID*. El error es que el modelo de datos está mal o es insuficiente para reflejar esta situación. Eso no se va a resolver metiendo fórmulas mágicas como columnas en la tabla, sino repensando el modelo de datos y adaptándolo para que sea robusto y responda a esta o a otras situaciones futuras.

Comment: @A.Cedano si despues de todo no puedes estar esperando a que esto toda la vida funcione asi, creo que mas bien desde un inicio no se planeo bien y ahopra solo se estan agregando parches.Cosa la cual causara un gran alboroto si se trata de un proyecto grande o peor aun si se trata del proyecto de una empresa.